# Config Vault Docker container with Consul Docker container

Tags: docker, consul, hashicorp-vault

I am trying to deploy Vault Docker image to work with Consul Docker image as its storage.

I have the following Json config file for the vault container:

```
 {
    "listener": [{
            "tcp": {
                    "address": "0.0.0.0:8200",
                    "tls_disable" : 1
            }
    }],

    "storage" :{
            "consul" : {
              "address" :"127.0.0.1:8500"
              "path"    :"vault/"

            }
    }
    "max_lease_ttl": "10h",
    "default_lease_ttl": "10h",
    "ui": true,
 }
```

Running consul container:

```
docker run -d -p 8501:8500 -it consul
```

and than running the vault container:

```
docker run -d -p 8200:8200 -v /root/vault:/vault --cap-add=IPC_LOCK vault server
```

Immediately after the vault container is up, it stop running, and when querying the logs I receive the following error:

```
Error detecting api address: Get http://127.0.0.1:8500/v1/agent/self: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:8500: connect: connection refused
Error initializing core: missing API address, please set in configuration or via environment
```

Any ideas why I am getting this error, and if I have any configuration problem?

Comment: docker-compose might really help here.

Comment: @MattSchuchard How so?

Comment: You can use the configuration to easily create a network interface between the two containers.

Comment: @MattSchuchard Any suggestions how to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are running docker, the "127.0.0.1" address you are pointing to is going to be inside your docker, but consul isn't listening there, it's listening on your docker-servers localhost!

So I would recommend that you do a link (--link consul:consul) when you start vault docker, and set "address" :"consul:8500" in the config.

Or, change "address" :"127.0.0.1:8500" to "address" :"172.17.0.1:8500" to let it connect to your docker servers forwarded 8500. The IP is whatever is set on your docker0 interface. Not as nice though since it's not official and that it can be changed in the configuration, so I recommend linking.

Comment: 172.17.01 is not the full IP, what number is it missing?

Comment: 172.17.0.1, that is the default docker network IP, but it can be overridden, so verify.